bloom version tagging for different ROS Distros
Say I have package A with:



Branch
Package Version
Git Tag




humble
1.0.0
1.0.0



I'm planning to have a new branch for jazzy support:



Branch
Package Version
Git Tag




humble
1.0.0
1.0.0


jazzy
TBD
TBD



I want to maintain these branches separately such that I will have the following:



Branch
Package Version
Git Tag




humble
1.0.0
humble:1.0.0


jazzy
1.0.0
jazzy:1.0.0



Where the same version number can be different source codes


From what I know, the git tag prefix can be set in $catkin_prepare_release -t <prefix>.
However, will this be allowed in bloom? Such that can specify a specific version per branch? 

I saw an old thread that says

"It looks like bloom's release tags don't use the full tag template when creating additional release tags." From bloom - same version number, different tag.

I'm not sure if what I want is possible.

Update as of October 18, 2024
If we have the another use case:



Source Code
Version
ROS Distro




+ feature1
2.0.0
humble, jazzy


feature1, + feature 2
2.1.0
jazzy


feature1, feature 2 + feature 3
2.2.0
jazzy



At this point humble's latest version is 2.0.0 and jazzy's latest version is 2.2.0.
If later on humble will be updated, is the following sequence possible (i.e.  catkin_prepare_release and bloom-release tools allow this)?

Add feature 3 only, resulting to 2.3.0 (humble)
Add feature 2, resulting to 2.2.0 (humble, jazzy)

where humble's version will go from 2.3.0 to 2.2.0




What you want to do can be done. The tracks don't double check against other tracks. For easiest avoidance of collisions you can just use separate release repos.
But you shouldn't do this!
The version number is intended to let others know what version of the code is provided by the package. If foo-1.0.0 is packaged in humble, I would expect to go to the upstream package and download tag 1.0.0.  if that is also packaged in jazzy, it is still expected to use the same source and tag. It has just been included in the jazzy distribution too. What you are doing by reusing the version numbers is communicating that they are the same content, which in this case is deceiving your users. If you're branching for new features, go to a new numbering series for the new distro, aka humble is 1.0.x and jazzy is 2.0.x.

This does makes sense. After looking at some references for semantic versioning link we will adapt it as well (i.e. version number = version of code). However, adapting 1.0.x or humble and 2.0.x for jazzy etc (given that we don't expect major differences at the beginning).
But forward looking, does $catkin_prepare_release and $bloom_release allow reverting back versions? (I've updated my question for this use case)

Versions can not go downward. If you release a lower version. The automatic updates will never deploy it because a lower version means an older release. Thus any release after 2.3 will be 2.4 no matter what feature is included.  if you're releasing from the same number series you should be releasing from the same branch with the same content. I would recommend you think about version numbers a little bit more freely where there's an infinite pool available, so incrementing to a new series has no cost.

Or you should commit that you will maintain dual compatibility and release the exact same thing to both distros. You want to do what is easy to understand for your users. Interleaving features in different orders in different distros is very unexpected.
